# push hash onto array in perl, result defies understanding

Tags: perl

Why does this..

```
my @menu;

my %el1 = ("element1" => "hello");
push @menu, \%el1;

my %el2 = ("element2" => "world");
push @menu, \%el2;

print to_json({"menu", @menu});
```

produce this..

```
{
    "menu": {
        "element1": "hello"
    },
    "HASH(0x18e2280)": null
}
```

and not this..

```
{
    "menu": {
        "element1": "hello",
        "element2": "world"
    }
}
```

Comment: also, enable warnings; `{'menu', @menu}` will give `Odd number of elements in anonymous hash` in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pushed two hash references onto `@menu`. So when you run this code:

```
print to_json({"menu", @menu});
```

It's exactly as if you ran:

```
print to_json({ "menu", \%el1, \%el2 });
```

The bit between `{ ... }` is interpreted as a hash so the first and third items are seen as hash keys and the second item is seen as a value. So you get the output that you see. (And, as has been pointed out in comments, you would get a warning under `use warnings` as that second key has no associated value).

I think that what you wanted to write was:

```
print to_json({ "menu", \@menu });
```

But even that isn't right. You get the following:

```
{
    "menu":[{
        "element1":"hello"
    },{
        "element2":"world"
    }]
}
```

The two hashes that you added to the array are still quite separate.

But what you actually want is a single hash. So create that instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my @menu;

my %el1 = (
    "element1" => "hello",
    "element2" => "world",
);

print to_json({"menu", \%el1});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you pass a **reference** to the array, the results are cleaner:

```
print to_json({"menu", \@menu});
```